# Remove WMS cache REST API?

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

Is there any REST API for remove wms cache of a layer in GeoServer?

I use `gwc/rest/masstruncate` but it returns status `500`. I can clear cache of a layer manually in TileCashign in GeoServer but I need API for this.

my request is: `curl -v -u user:pass -POST -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d "<truncateLayer><layerName>workspace:layer</layerName></truncateLayer>"  "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/rest/masstruncate/"`

and my response is: `Truncation failed`

Comment: What does the log file show?

Comment: @lan I edit my question

Comment: turn logging up and look again

Comment: The same error occurred again

Comment: but there was a stacktrace?